# Show that a set of complex functions is finite

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I got this problem and I have absolutely no clue how to solve it, or even how to start it -

Let $r \in\Bbb R$. Show that the set $\{z\in\Bbb C \,|\ z^r=2\}$ is finite if and only if $r$ is rational.

Comment: How this set form a group? Is not obvious to me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't study mathematics in English so it was free translation from my language. I fixed it.

Comment: Try analyzing the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}|z^r=1\}$ first. When is this set finite? What is the relationship between this one and your set?

Comment: Maybe some stuff like inverse function theorem in the complex context might be helpful.. for natural values we can conclude by Ruffini.

Comment: For $z^r=1$ I'm concluding that r=0

Comment: Am I correct with this calculation?